GetAuthenticationStateAsync() is not hitting with Authorize attribute
I have created a .NET Aspire project and implemented JWT authentication. In .NET Aspire, it creates 4 projects Api, Apphost, Service defaults, Blazor Server App.
When I am refreshing page in my Blazor server app without [Authorize] attribute, GetAuthenticationStateAsync() is hit and it is working fine.
When I am refreshing the page with [Authorize] attribute,  the GetAuthenticationStateAsync() method is not hit. I am not getting any errors - just a blank screen.
I have tried several ways like registering order of the services.
Can anyone help me to resolve this?

can you provide your .razor page code? as well as your App.razor and services registering code?

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  As it stands your question can't be answered without making a lot of [probably wrong] guesses.

"I am not getting any errors - just a blank screen." - Does your IAppBuilder pipeline have UseExceptionHandler or UseDeveloperExceptionPage or a debugger attached?

You could create a CustomAuthorizationHandler and bypass the authorization when HttpContext is not null.
    public class CustomAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IAuthorizationRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
        {
            if (context.Resource != null)
            {
                // Bypass authorization
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

Register it to program.cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomAuthorizationHandler>();

